# What might be the causes if the change to template was not reflected in the browser?

Tags: django

I made some changes to my Django template but it could not reflected in the browser(chrome). However, if I open another browser(safari), the change were shown.

What might be the cause of this phenomenon? I am using the Django development server.

Comment: Sometimes browsers cache information like stylesheets and scripts. Force reload to make it update these.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean style changes like css or js code. In this case, even on localhost, your browser stores your static files (css, js etc.) in cache memory. To force the reload on those files, force refresh the page. (In chrome, either press `ctrl+f5` on windows, `cmd+shift+r` on mac, or open a private tab.

Comment: by the way, the change was in the html template file.

Comment: this is weird. HTML files are not cached in browser (because they are constantly changing like when adding new blog post). Any change in pure HTML file should be instantly visible in you web browser BUT maybe it was a case of just refreshing the page. So remember in future - when you don't see new styles from static files - ```force refresh``` but when you don't see HTML changes like new ```<div>Hello world</div>``` is not visible - something is wrong - Try to reload and resolve the problem